# How can i enable exact match using solrj?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Are there way to enable exact match using solrj? I need to do it dynamically by parameter change

I saw some examples like this:

```
 @Override
 public TokenFilter create(TokenStream input) {
  return new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(input, minGramSize, maxGramSize, preserveOriginal);
 }
}
```

But didn't understood how to get it working in code

Comment: You don't do that through SolrJ directly - you'll have to have a field on the Solr side that is the exact version that you want to match, then query against that - usually a `string` field or a field with a `KeywordTokenizer` and a lower case filter if you want your matches to be case insensitive. An EdgeNGramFilter (which you have included from the source) would generate tokens that are ngrams from the start of the word (so `w`, `wo`, `wor`, `word`) and would match against any of those. How you do those exact matches would then depend on your defined schema.